# Forward domain with sub directories to other domains with subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a client who loves domains and loves even more to forward domains. Many of these domains to not have websites associated with them. They are just used for marketing and forwarding. I know how to easily forward a domain to another, but what I am curious about is how to forward specific url's of these domains to other specific url's.

For example:

www.site1.com/directory --> www.site2.com/example

And then at the same time:

www.site1.com --> www.site3.com/example

Is the only way to have this done be through using .htaccess? Any other method? At this point these domains do not have .htaccess files even associated with them as they are directly forwarding using the control panel of 1and1.com.

And if .htaccess is the only way to go, is there a simpler way to construct these files?

Comment: You can setup multiple domains to point to the same IP address of your server. Then have apache listen for each domain and based on the `HTTP_HOST` redirect as you wish. You could even do something like have a specific host map to a directory while any other host maps to a single php file that forwards/maps/redirects elsewhere. Giving you the option to use php for most of the work because it is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For above you can have these rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.site3.com/example [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory(/.*)?$ http://www.site2.com/example$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```