# Point a domain to a sub-directory of another domain

Tags: dns, ip, hosting

How can you point one domain to a sub-directory of another domain without using an `.htaccess` file, forwarding, or frames?

I have two domains (`example.com` and `xyz.com`) and one host. The first domain `example.com` points to the root directory in the hosting account. I would like the second domain `xyz.com` to point to the `/xyz/` sub-directory of the hosting account. I don't want to use any redirects that change the URL, nor do I want to use any frames. If I go to `xyz.com/page.html` I should get served the exact same page as `example.com/xyz/page.html`.

I know this is possible via an `.htaccess` file ([Forward domain with sub directories to other domains with subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465251/forward-domain-with-sub-directories-to-other-domains-with-subdirectories)), but I'd prefer an explanation that's OS-agnostic, and deals more with configurations. I'm not experienced in hosting/DNS/nameservers/etc, but I'm hoping there is a solution that uses one of those. From my searching it seems like this is not possible by only modifying the DNS or nameservers. Perhaps it's possible by creating a new IP address that resolves to the subdirectory and then pointing the DNS of `xyz.com` to that IP?

If this is not possible, I'll also accept an answer that explains *why* this is not possible.

Comment: This is really a [webmastering](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) question. You say you have "one host"? Does your account support parked or add-on domains? This would be the much preferred/easiest way to solve this. What type of hosting do you have... Apache/Linux? "Windows hosting" - What webserver? IIS is more usual on Windows (in a production environment). The same method won't work on both Apache and IIS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a webmastering question and should be moved to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: I modified my question to look for a non-htaccess solution (thus making it *not* a duplicate). My account may have parked/add-on domains, I'm not sure. It's currently apache/linux but I'm looking for a more high-level solution that's OS-agnostic if possible.

Comment: If you can move this to "webmastering", that would be great. Otherwise I will type it up again over there.